# Bug in Stockfish/Suggesting bad move

Tags: stockfish

Why does Stockfish suggest this move in this position for white? It is a clear losing position if the king moves that way, as supposed to a draw if the king chooses f7 instead...

[image]

This is a real game that ended up this way.

Comment: FEN is: 6Q1/8/6K1/1k6/8/8/6r1/8 w - - 0 1

Comment: Can't it be hash colision? In very large sample of PC games there are occasionally blunders like this. I saw similar in Komodo game.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but I suspect Stockfish just hasn't completed its move or flushed the current move to your UI. Or the UI you are using isn't giving all the information.

My Stockfish (6) gives '1. Kf7', unsurprisingly.

Comment: Why do you use Stockfish 6?

Comment: @Habbo Um, it's just the one I installed last. What's it up to now?

Answer (score 1):

I tried Stockfish 8 for your position, but unable to reproduce the issue. Your depth is very low for this simple position. Can you wait a few more seconds in your analysis?